# What are the semantics of "proguardInJars" in SBT Android-Plugin?

Tags: android, scala, sbt, proguard, sbt-android-plugin

In SBT Android Plugin, in proguardTask, there is a value `proguardInJars`.
In my simple test project it contains `C:\Users\Administrator\.sbt\boot\scala-2.9.1\lib\scala-library.jar`.

It is then combined with my own compiled classes into another value `inJars`.

However, it is combined by appending something to it. Here's the code from jberkel/android-plugin that does that:

```
val manifestr = List("!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF", "R.class", "R$*.class", "TR.class", "TR$.class", "library.properties")
val sep = JFile.pathSeparator
val inJars = ("\"" + classDirectory.absolutePath + "\"") +: proguardInJars.map("\"" + _ + "\""+manifestr.mkString("(", ",!**/", ")"))
```

I am wondering is anyone knows the semantics of that added stuff.
Also, if I were to break `inJars` into separate values, would I still need to append that manifest stuff to `proguardInJars` in order for `proguardTask` to run without problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android plugin is preparing the `injars` command line argument for ProGuard at that point.
ProGuard uses generalized classpaths to figure out which files from a jar to consider, and which not to, a form of file matchers within the jars.

For example, `.../scala-library.jar(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,!**/R.class,!**/R$*.class,!**/TR.class,!**/TR$.class,!**/library.properties)` means that files `R/TR.class` or classfiles starting with `R$`/`TR$` should not (`!`) be taken into consideration as an input.

See here:

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

Click on `class_path` to show more details about the generalized classpath format that ProGuard uses.